# Function Complexity Analysis

Tags: c++, complexity-theory

How can I get the cost of this function? I know it is O(√n) but other than trying a lot of n values and getting a pattern I don't know how to find it.

```
void foo(int n) {
    int x = 2;
    int y = 1;
    while(y <= n) {
        y += x;
        ++x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is result of `sum(1,2,3,4,...,t)`? it equals:

```
sum(1,2,3,4,...,t)=(t*(t+1))/2
```

So `x` in loop is increased by `O(t^2)`. So the number that `while` loops will be amortized to `O(sqrt(n))`, because `y` is increased by `x` till it reaches to `n`.

Answer (score 3):

Look at `y` values, after `x` iterations the `y` value would be:

```
step   1 2 3 4     x
y=     1+2+3+4+...+x
```

(1) The loop stops when the `y>n` which means when `1+2+...+x>n`. At this point (when `y>n`), we iterated `x` times (yes, the same `x` in the previous equations!)

(2) We also know `1+2+...+x = x(x+1)/2 = O(x^2)`

(1)+(2): The loops stops when `x^2>n` or after `√n` iterations.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the value of `y` after `i` iterations:

`y = 2+...+i`
The loops ends when `y > n`, so what you are really asking is at which iteration `i` does this condition become true?

`y > n`  is really `2+..+i > n`. We know that `2+..+i = (n(n+1))/2 -1` so
`y>n` becomes `(i(i+1))/2 > n+1` which solves for `i^2 +i > 2n+2`. 
Should be easy enough to see that `i` is `O(sqrt(n))` from here.
**The first value at which the inequality `y > n` holds is proportional to `sqrt(2n+2)`.**

---

Note that `2+..+i = (n(n+1))/2 -1` because of the famous closed formula `sum(1,2,3,...,k) = 1+2+3+...+k = (k(k+1))/2`